# Docker Compose MongoDB connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a NodeJS server that needs to connect to MongoDB, everything is built with docker compose, including NGINX.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  api01: &api
    image: localimage/local:latest
    hostname: api01
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.6"
          memory: "200MB"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - default
  api02:
    <<: *api
    hostname: api02
    ports:
      - 8082:8080

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    hostname: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongo
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    networks:
      - default

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - api01
      - api02
    ports:
      - 9999:9999
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.17"
          memory: "10MB"
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    name: networkname
```

The NGINX part works fine and I can communicate to api01 and api02 with no problems through the load balancer port 9999. But my APIs can't connect to the MongoDB image for some reason.

**db.js**

```js
const url = 'mongodb://mongo:pass@mongo:27017'
await mongoose.connect(url);
```

If I modify the docker-file to only build the MongoDB and run the API locally, I can connect to it with no problems changing the `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`, but it doesn't work if I built everything in the docker-compose file.

The specific error that I get is:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.28.0.2:27017
```

Comment: Hi, when running services in Docker Compose, I THINK containers communicate using service names as hostnames. So in your `db.js`, MongoDB connection URL should use  service name `mongo` instead of `localhost`. Something like `mongodb://mongo:pass@mongo:27017`

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub I'm sorry, I had already tested using the url `mongodb://mongo:pass@mongo:27017`, forgot to mention it on the question, I will update it!

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it work?  There's a real case where services can start up before the database is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Finally made that work. I had two problems actually: My API was trying to connect to MongoDB before the container started, solved that for now by running the DB container before the APIs: `docker compose up mongo -d´ and then after it was initialized:` docker compose up nginx api01 api02 -d`

Then, I noticed that I was getting another error! My authentication method wasn't working, so I had to change the following:
**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
mongo:
  environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongo
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=rbe
```

**db.js**

```js
const url = `mongodb://mongo:pass@mongo:27017/rbe?authSource=admin`;
  await mongoose
    .connect(url)
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

In the authentication problem, I'm not sure what **really** caused the problem, maybe was the way I declared the password and the user `enviroment` in the docker compose file, maybe was the missing database name, or maybe the problem was not using `?authSource=admin` in the URI, whatever.